# Spark: partition .txt.gz files and convert to parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to convert all text files in a folder that are gzipped to parquet. I wonder if I need to gunzip them first or not.
Also, I'd like to partition each file in 100 parts.
This is what I have so far:

```
sc.textFile("s3://bucket.com/files/*.gz").repartition(100).toDF()
    .write.parquet("s3://bucket.com/parquet/")
```

Is this correct? Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: usually when we load gzip file in spark context it will create only one partition, while writing you can repartition.

Comment: Hi @user7693121 can you give me an example in code? when would I be writing? I'm new to spark

Comment: can you try this sc.textFile("s3://bucket.com/files/*.gz").toDF().repartition(100)
    .write.parquet("s3://bucket.com/parquet/")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to uncompress files individually. The only problem with reading gzip files directly is that your reads won't be parallelized. That means, irrespective of the size of the file, you will only get one partition per file because `gzip` is not a splittable compression codec.

You might face problems if individual files are greater than a certain size (2GB?) because there's an upper limit to Spark's partition size.

Other than that your code looks functionally alright.

Comment: thanks for your answer. you mentioned that I'll get one partition since it's not splittable. so the call to repartition(100) won't work? or is it one partition after reading but repartition(100) will indeed partition it in 100 parts? do you think it's worth gunzipping before?

Comment: It will. The dataset will get repartitioned to 100 partitions before you write to parquet. It's only worth uncompressing if the size of individual gzip file is huge otherwise Spark should be able to handle it.

Comment: one more thing, should I be calling repartition(100) before or after .toDF() ?

Comment: The only difference I can think of is that if you call it after `.toDF()` i.e on a dataframe, you can pass additional parameters like the column name(s) on which you want to repartition.